# Three reference letters, two academic and one professional

Tags: phd, application, recommendation-letter

I am applying to a highly prestigious university in the UK for a PhD position. The usual norm here is that PhD's usually (unlike the US) require 2 rec letters, however this specific program asks for 3, and these 3 are for the course itself, it's not like one is for a scholarship and the other 2 are for the application, all three are for the application.

The PhD is in bioelectronics/neuroscience, and I have 2 solid rec letters from my uni supervisors, so that's fine but I don't have a third one! so I'm thinking of asking my manager at an oil company I have worked at before, ofc the letter won't have as much impact as the first two, but would something like this be really bad? or really wrong?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you read other Q&A here under the tag [tag:recommendation-letter] ? [Maybe adding the term "who"](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Brecommendation-letter%5D+who)? How did those Q&A help and what are you still unsure about?

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for the links, They were helpful however I still don't know if asking someone within the industry (who is at a managerial level and not that technical) is a good idea for a PhD position, provided that his letter is third to the first two which are from people with a strong record (high citation numbers, awards and so on).

Comment: There are many many people who have asked exactly the same question here: "who should be my third referee", given similar circumstances to what you describe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A professional letter is fine. It can focus on your personality, your characteristics, your leadership, and your willingness to do hard works. All of those are highly valued by a PhD program. It would be even better if you've led some research projects under his supervision or leadership.

It would be even better better (double betters) that he assures your ability of seeking funding or other research supports (such as data, instruments, and manpower) from the industry.

However, if he cannot say those things, I would like to suggest you to find a professor in one of your seminar course or project course that you did a small research project in that course.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I guess I never looked at it from that angle! :) but it does make sense.